# Convert docx file to Google Docs and place in same folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I need to convert docx files inside a folder and place the created GDocs file beside the .docx as the same name without .docx extension

I do not want to use `folder.addFile(doc);DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(doc)` because its a overhead and I want to place the file in the folder itself rather than creating the converted file in root and then moving it besides docx.

I have tried with

```
function myFunction() {
  var docx = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Dummy.docx').next();
  var newDoc = Drive.newFile();
  var blob =docx.getBlob();
  var file=Drive.Files.insert(newDoc,blob,{convert:true});
  DocumentApp.openById(file.id).setName(docx.getName());  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to convert DOCX file to Google Document.
- You want to put the converted Google Document to the same folder of the DOCX file.
- You want to set the filename of Google Document by removing the extension of the filename of the DOCS file.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to propose to use the method of "Files: copy" of Drive API. By this, the converted Google Document has been automatically renamed as the filename without the extension of `.docx`. And, the converted Google Document is put to the same folder with the DOCX file. I thought that this situation might be suitable for achieving your goal.

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this, [please confirm whether Drive API is enabled at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services), again.

```
function myFunction() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('Dummy.docx');
  if (!file.hasNext()) return;
  var document = Drive.Files.copy({}, file.next().getId(), {convert: true});
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(document.id);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/copy)

Comment: How do I modify the code, if I need to copy to a different folder instead copying in source folder itself?

Comment: @Code Guy Thank you for replying. When you want to put the converted file to the specific folder, please modify `var document = Drive.Files.copy({}, file.next().getId(), {convert: true})` to `var document = Drive.Files.copy({parents: [{id: "### folder ID ###"}]}, file.next().getId(), {convert: true})`. In this case, the folder ID of the specific folder is used.

Comment: I am glad. Thanks Tanaike. I am Darren. I adore you so much and you have saved tons of our time. Really grateful

Comment: @Code Guy Hi Darren. Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score -1):

You can specify the folder where the file should be created using its [metadata](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create):

```
function myFunction() {
  // Set target Folder
  var folderID = 'FOLDER_ID';
  
  // Get .docx based on its name
  var docx = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).getFilesByName('Dummy.docx').next();
  
  // Specify file name and parent folder
  var fileMetadata = {
    title: docx.getName(),
    parents: [{id: folderID}]
  };
  
  // Convert .docx to Docs
  Drive.Files.insert(fileMetadata, docx.getBlob(), {convert:true});
  
  // Send .docx to Trash
  docx.setTrashed(true);
}
```

For this to work, you need to enable the Drive advanced services: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive

Comment: Using setTrashed isnt an efficient technique/

Comment: You don't need to delete the file if you don't want. Why is it not efficient though?